# Why is my service not changing my instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, methods, null, instance-variables

My service is supposed to match the current user with an opponent. I have a method in my service that is supposed to find this opponent but it's not saving it in my controller. I realize this is a very basic question but I'm very new to rails, thank you!

Here is my service:

```
class MatchUser
  attr_accessor :user_params

  def initialize(user_params)
    @user_params = user_params
  end


  def match(opponent)
    return false if user_params[:matched] == true
    @unmatched_users = User.where(matched: false)
    @unique_unmatched_users = @unmatched_users.where.not(id: user_params[:id])
    @same_league_unmatched_users = @unique_unmatched_users.where(league_id:
    user_params[:league_id])
    return false if @same_league_unmatched_users.empty?
    opponent = @same_league_unmatched_users.sample
    opponent.faceoff_date = Time.now
    user_params[:faceoff_date] = Time.now

    opponent.save!
  end
end
```

Here is the part in my controller where I'm getting an error when I try to assign @matched_user_team because @matched_user is nil

```
    @user = current_user
    @matching = MatchUser.new(@user)
    if @matching.match(@matched_user) 
      @matched_user_team = @matched_user.teams.last.chars
    end
```

Comment: Where are you defining `@matched_user`?

Comment: That's the thing, it's supposed to be defined inside my service (the parameter passed is opponent)

Comment: Can you post the code that defines `@matched_user`? Regardless, I would use a debugging tool (e.g. byebug) to inspect the variable to see what's going on.